# iMacros script for Facebook Comment

Tags: facebook, comments, imacros

I am trying to create macros for adding comment in "Facebook comment box" in my blog

the code:

```
VERSION BUILD=9002379
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://www.mydomain.com
FRAME NAME=f21bb5a05134b1c
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ACTION:/ajax/connect/feedback.php ATTR=NAME:text CONTENT=great
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/ajax/connect/feedback.php ATTR=ID:u_0_2
```

always get this error

```
Error -1300: Cannot find HTML element of type "TEXTAREA:" with attribute(s) "NAME:text".. Line 6: TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ACTION:/ajax/connect/feedback.php ATTR=NAME:text CONTENT=great
```

is this possible to be automate using iMacros? and in case, can the same code used with different blogs

thanks

Comment: Record the Macro, that would be easier!?

Comment: the above code is from the recorded script!